# Can a MAC address be used as a reliable part of a rights management (DRM) scheme?

Tags: authentication, networking, mac-address

We're currently writing some software that we want to protect. We thought that registering a user's MAC address in a database upon activation of the software seemed viable; we can profile and grab that with a Java applet, (is there a better way?) so getting it isn't too much of a problem. However, we want their computer to only run the application, and download application files/updates from the server when their MAC address has been verified with their one on-file. We understand that this means a lockdown to one computer, but special changes can be made on request.

What would be the best way to verify their MAC address, to see if it exists in the database, and then serve them the files to run the application? (And to simply run it on subsequent requests, to prevent re-downloading.)

Comment: MAC addresses are only approximately globally unique. As there are legitimate reasons to alter your MAC address, you really cannot assume that it is a invariant machine ID. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address

Comment: @msw Generally, MAC addresses change infrequently enough to cope with a manual process of customers contacting the vendor. However, not ideal if it's mission-critical software and hardware needs replacing.

Comment: MAC address information is part of the IP network layer.  You don't need some applet to get the information, the client is doing that for you already.  Also, MAC addresses are trivial to spoof, so if this is being used as a security measure, I really don't think its going to offer you the protection you need.

Comment: User may also have more than one Network Interface Adapter resulting in more than one MAC, e.g. WiFi card, Ethernet card, USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments to the question indicate: no, you cannot use a MAC address effectively for Digital Rights Management (DRM).